# How to create a pem key in string format from base64 encoded key

Tags: javascript, jwt, sign, bitcoinj

I'm trying to create a pem key from a ecdsa private key, I have to use a pem string in another function to create a JWT but when I'm trying

`var base64key = 'MDc4M2UwODJiNmFhMmVmOWIxZDdjN2YwMTYxMGM4M2ZkZTk2OTE3OWVlNzdlYzBmNTJmY2NiNjBhMDBjNTA0OQ==';
var privKey64 = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n'+base64key+'\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----';
var sJWS = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(null, {alg: "ES256"}, privKey64);`

So when I'm trying to feed this pem key to sign function I'm getting following error

> *init failed:malformed plain PKCS8 private key

So I suspect that the pem key generated is not of valid format