# How to create a .pem file with aes key

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, pem

i have to create an aes-256 key and store it in a .pem file. I am using `RAND_bytes()` to simply create a 256 bit random key. After this how can i save this to a pem file. 
I have looked at [Reading and writing rsa keys to a pem file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647220/reading-and-writing-rsa-keys-to-a-pem-file-in-c) and [openssl pem](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/pem.html). But i am not working with RSA keys.

I suspect my task is much simpler like [create pem from base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314793/how-to-create-a-pem-key-in-string-format-from-base64-encoded-key) but not much help.

PS: This key will be used to encrypt a self signed digital certificate.

EDIT: looking around more i found that i could use bio to covert to pem, something like`PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey` but it takes EVP_PKEY format as argument. So how can i convert char buf to EVP_PKEY. i found d2i_PublicKey but it involves RSA and am unsure how RSA would fit into picture here.

Comment: Given your requirements and looking at the ***BIG*** picture, you typically want to encrypt a file using an [Integrated Encryption Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). As a side note, a *"self signed digital certificate..."* is generally considered public information, and it usually does not have encryption applied to it.

Answer (score 3):

AES key is just a random byte array. You can simple store the bytes in a file without any structure.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert aes key to .pem by using PEMWriter class of bouncyCastle library.

http://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html

Comment: BouncyCastle is **Java**.  This question is tagged C and OpenSSL.